# Can I pre-load an Animation?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg

I have an svg animation that uses lots of filters, but it doesn't run quickly enough.  Is there any code I use that would make it pre-calculate the result images (load them all at the start) so that when the animation starts, it can execute the code at full speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the BufferedRenderingProperty to "dynamic"

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#BufferedRenderingProperty

Comment: that's unlikely to help anything here.

Comment: because? svg can be rendered a lot smoother if the BufferedRenderingProperty is set correctly to 'dynamic' (on big animations) instead of the default 'auto' if it is not set at all. So why do you think this will "not help anything" ?

Comment: what browser does it make a difference in? (I implemented buffered-rendering in Opera, and know for sure that setting it to 'dynamic' won't have any effect in the given scenario).

Comment: The few tries I had with svg animations (I still prefer flash if I'm not targeting ios devices) I had the impression that ~ALL of them  perform a lot smoother with 'dynamic' buffered rendering even Opera. With 'all' I mean chrome, safari, firefox and opera, since ie is unlikely to do anything as I expect ...different story ;) even the coverflow-esque animation with alphablending shading and different other filters went very smooth (allthough opera tends to move my text a bit up), but if you KNOW it doesn't then that was perhaps a psychosomatic improvement only ;)

Comment: AFAIK none of chrome, safari, firefox or IE implement `buffered-rendering` for svg. Nevertheless, if you have some data suggesting otherwise I encourage you to post it.

Comment: I'm baffled! That means I forgot to disable cache for testing??? luckily my client already nodded those through. Unfortunately I cannot publish any of those due to the contract, and to be honest I'm not too eager to create any new svg animation (I still like flash better;)) But since we seem to get into chitchat here I suggest we just forget about it ;) I admit YOU know way more about svg than I do.